# Write visualforce page without using iterator

Tags: visualforce

Below is visualforce page i have created, Is there any way i can write this VF page without using VF iterator? Or using Javascript?

```
 <apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="AccountOwner">
    <style type="text/css">
       .outBorder {
        border:3px outset black;
       }
       .inBorder{
        border-top:2px solid black;
       }
      </style>
              <div align="center">
              <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts_owned}" var="account" styleclass="outBorder" width="300px">
              <apex:facet name="caption">Accounts Owned by Current User</apex:facet>
              <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
              <apex:column styleclass="inBorder">
              <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"/>
              </apex:column>
              </apex:dataTable>
              </div>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: There is, yes; however, the apex tags that iterate over a collection are generally the right tools for this job. Why are you looking to re-invent the wheel here? Doing so would likely make your visualforce page longer, and less [DRY](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiJ85GwvLzNAhWGKh4KHUUDCxgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDon%27t_repeat_yourself&usg=AFQjCNH27hysufwHVMAVfZEp4cSFurM2uQ).

Comment: @DerekF My senior told me to do like that, i have no idea how can i achieve that without using iterator.

Comment: Hmm...I think going to your senior and asking for an explanation why `<apex:dataTable>`, `<apex:pageBlockTable>`, or `<apex:repeat>` can't be used is a good idea. You can also then ask them for some hints about how to accomplish this. It may be embarrassing to ask that, but I think it's better to admit that you don't know (or understand) something than it is to pretend that you do.

Comment: If your senior insists on being tricky, generate all the html in your controller and output it all in a single outputtext with escape set to false.

Comment: so Javascript is or is not an option?